# Applying dynamic CSS style to marker of google map

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that we can dynamically apply **label** or **icon image** or **css class** to marker of google in angularJs, but I am unable to dig out how we can apply dynamic css style to marker. I have to dynamically generate markers on the google map and color them dynamically. Are we able to do it?

I have tried following but doesn't seems to be working

```
  var putMarker = function(lat,long,color) {              
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
        map: map,
        labelStyle: {backgroundColor:"#ff00ff", height:"5px", width:"5px", borderRadius:"50px"},
        icon: 'img/mapView.png',
        label: (markers.length + 1) + '',
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        isDraggable: false
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      //extend the bounds to include each marker's position
      bounds.extend(marker.position);

      //now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

Comment: Why u not try to give style your icon? You can also use MarkerImage class for resize etc.

Comment: how can I give style to my icon? any solutions.. and what is markerImage class?

Answer (score 0):

MarkerImage depricated, you can use Icon class.

```
var customSizeImage = {
  url: place.icon,
  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
   map: map,
   icon: customSizeImage
});
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a single textual character on a marker, you can use a marker label. If you need greater customization, you can define an icon to show instead of the default marker image. Defining an icon involves setting a number of properties that determine the visual behavior of the marker.

A [marker label](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons) is a single textual character that appears inside a marker. You can specify a marker label as either a string or a MarkerLabel object that includes a string and other label properties. In both cases, only the first character of the specified string is displayed on the marker.

When creating a marker, you can specify a label property in the MarkerOptions object. Alternatively, you can call setLabel() on the Marker object to set the label on an existing marker.

Here is some example code:

```
// This example adds a marker to indicate the position of Bondi Beach in Sydney,
// Australia.
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 4,
center: {lat: -33, lng: 151}
});

var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
map: map,
icon: image
});
}
```

For more information check this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#introduction).